# I am having problem installing Microsoft.rdlcDesigner for Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded the Microsoft.rdlcDesigner from the marketplace.visualstudio.com site. Upon download, i began installing it and installation was going on just fine until I accidentally canceled the setup.Ever since then, installation has been showing me some errors -" This extension is not installable on any currently installed products". I have checked Vs2019 to see if rdlc report designer is installed and could not find any trace of the report designer.  Although i have both Vs2012 and VS2019 installed in my Pc, i only want the rdlc designer to be installed on VS2019 ( since it is already installed on VS2012). The error log was suggesting that there is same product in VS2012. I have tried a lot of things but could not get the designer installed. Please what do I do? See installation log below:

```
2/26/2021 9:53:00 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2/26/2021 9:53:00 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/26/2021 9:53:02 AM - Initializing Install...
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM - Extension Details...
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Identifier      : 617ad572-c5b7-415c-b166-b2969077f719
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Name            : Microsoft RDLC Report Designer
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Author          : Microsoft
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Version         : 15.3.1
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Description     : RDLC Designer and projects for ASP.Net and Windows Forms for Reporting Services Report Viewer Control
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  Locale          : en-US
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  MoreInfoURL     : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/01a821c4-2920-400c-be03-93d26c749bb1.aspx
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  InstalledByMSI  : False
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
2/26/2021 9:53:05 AM - 
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -  SignedBy        : Microsoft Corporation
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -  Certificate Info : [Subject]
  CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

[Serial Number]
  330000026ECE6AE5984BFC96A900000000026E

[Not Before]
  9/6/2018 10:00:30 PM

[Not After]
  9/6/2019 10:00:30 PM

[Thumbprint]
  99B6246883B4B32EA59AE18B36945D205A876800

2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -  Supported Products : 
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -          Version : [15.0,17.0)
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM - 
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM -  References      : 
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM - 
2/26/2021 9:53:28 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - Found installed product - ssms
2/26/2021 9:53:37 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Your Visual Studio 2019

Go to Extensions => Manage Extensions => Search => Microsoft RDLC Report Designer

[image: RDLC Report Designer]

Restart VS2019 and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Bilal Bin Zia. I just tried this now. After restarting Visual Studio the installation began and another error was encountered "Could not find instance engine". Modification failed. here is the error log:     2/26/2021 11:07:41 AM - Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find setup engine instance.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineUtility.GetCurrentSetupInstance(IEngineHost engineHost)

Comment: I suggest you run your visual studio Installer => More => Repair. you might have removed a setup instance from **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances** accidently.

Comment: "Visual Studio extension development" might be missing. repair will add it again or you can install it individually.

Comment: Okay, I will try that out and give you feedback. Thanks once again.

Comment: Sure. Happy Coding

Comment: It worked! After repairing as you suggested, I was able to install the report designer. I express my profound gratitude to you. Thanks big time.

Comment: No Problem at all.

Comment: Addiionally: It's quite a bit later but the following also might be required depending on what kind of antivirus you have installed. You have to allow the Xamarin. Messaging IDB to run under specified security settings